# Rails: Access class method of a model inside the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

In order to access the same array in different parts of my app, I stored the array in the corresponding Model, using class method to retrieve the array.

In the code bellow, **codes** are used in views (to generate the select drop down) and in the same model (to validate passed value).

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :code, presence: true, inclusion: { in: self.codes }

  def self.codes
    return ["OBJ", "SER", "REC"]
  end

end
```

But using this, generates the following error:

```
undefined method `codes' for #<Class:0x000001074ddc50>
```

Even removing the `self.` in the inclusion, doesn't solve the problem (undefined local variable).

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `codes` method is declared after you've used it in your validation - when the validation line is executed the method has not yet been defined, hence the error.

If you place the validation after the `codes` method it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can define it as a constant at a top of your model

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  CODES = ["OBJ", "SER", "REC"]
```

Than you can access it like this Request::CODES

validations will look like this

```
 validates :code, presence: true, inclusion: { in: CODES }
```